# Access field names from firebase realtime db through flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase realtime database in my flutter app. My data looks something like this :

[image]

This is my code :

```
var uid = user?.uid;
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('uids/$uid/sessions');
ref.onValue.listen((event) {
      for (final child in event.snapshot.children) {
        var dataObject = child.value.toString();
        print(dataObject);
      }
    }, onError: (error) {});
```

It gives me this output :

```
I/flutter (16144): {2:9: Example728, 3:15: Example644, 1:45: Example, 2:11: Example184, 2:7: Example}
I/flutter (16144): {2:16: Example440, 2:26: Example124, 2:22: Example515}
```

I want to extract information from this jsonObject. But I have 0 idea how to do it. Do I have to make a model? If yes then how? Because the fields are actually time stamps. And I would want to access them as well as I have to display it on the screen with the date (5-11-2022  and  6-11-2022) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside the listen

```
//dataObject = child.value
    Map dataObject = {
      "5-11-2022": {
        "2:9": "Example728",
        "3:15": "Example644",
        "1:45": "Example",
        "2:11": "Example184",
        "2:7": "Example",
      },
      "6-11-2022": {
        "2:16": "Example440",
        "2:26": "Example124",
        "2:22": "Example515",
      },
    };

    for (MapEntry item in dataObject.entries) {
      String day = item.key.toString();
      debugPrint("day: $day");
      for (MapEntry item2 in dataObject[item.key].entries) {
        String hour = item2.key.toString();
        String value = item2.value.toString();
        debugPrint("hour: $hour value: $value");
      }
    }
```